# The fastest way to work with ndimage in python?

Tags: performance, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, vectorization

I have function which iterates over **ndimage** (converts image from one color space to another).
It works too slow (2 cores CPU, 2.3 GHz, image size = 3 MP):

1) Brute-force approach (loop): 27 seconds

```
def imageRGBtoYCrCb(rgb_image):
    """ Converts image from RGB to YCrCb. OVERWRITES. 
    """
    w, h = rgb_image.shape[0], rgb_image.shape[1] 
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            rgb = rgb_image[x][y]
            ycrcb = RGBtoYCrCb(rgb)
            rgb_image[x][y] = ycrcb         
    return rgb_image

def RGBtoYCrCb(rgb):
    """ Converts RGB vector to YCrCb vector

    Keyword arguments:
    rgb -- list of size 3: [r,g,b]

    Returns: YCrCr color (list of size 3: [y,cr,cb])
    """

    r,g,b = float(rgb[0]),float(rgb[1]),float(rgb[2])
    y = 0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b
    cb = 128 - 0.1687*r - 0.3313*g + 0.5*b 
    cr = 128 + 0.5*r - 0.4187*g - 0.0813*b

    return [y,cr,cb]
```

2) Vectorization approach (**numpy.apply_along_axis**, **numpy.dot**): 90 seconds (**???**)

```
import numpy as np

matr_to_ycrcb_mult = np.array([ [0.299, 0.587, 0.114], [0.5, -0.4187, -0.0813], [-0.1687, -0.3313, 0.5] ])
vec_to_ycrcb_add = np.array([ 0, 128, 128 ])
matr_to_rgb_mult = np.array([ [1,1.402,0], [1,-0.71414,-0.34414], [1,0,1.772] ])
vec_to_rgb_add = np.array([ -128*1.402, 128*1.05828, -128*1.772 ])

def imageRGBtoYCrCb(rgb_image):
    rgb_image = np.apply_along_axis(RGBtoYCrCb, 2, rgb_image)
    return rgb_image

def RGBtoYCrCb(rgb):
    """ Converts RGB vector to YCrCb vector
    """
    return np.dot(matr_to_ycrcb_mult,rgb) + vec_to_ycrcb_add
```

**Is there faster way to process ndimage?**
Have I implemented vectorization concepts correctly?

Comment: By the way, I think you mean "ndarray" rather than "ndimage". `np.ndarray` is the basic numpy array class, whereas `ndimage` is a submodule in scipy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply_along_axis` is a convenience function but it does not really vectorize the operation, as the iteration still takes place in Python land.

Your `RGBtoYCrCb` function only needs a tiny change to operate the whole image.  In function `new_RGBtoYCrCb2` we slice out `r`, `g`, `b` (these are only views into the original image data, no copying) and then stack them together at the end.

You can also reshape and use a dot product without slicing and glueing, which may be faster (function `new_RGBtoYCrCb2`):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.data import coffee

def imageRGBtoYCrCb(rgb_image):
    """ Converts image from RGB to YCrCb. OVERWRITES. 
    """
    w, h = rgb_image.shape[0], rgb_image.shape[1] 
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            rgb = rgb_image[x][y]
            ycrcb = RGBtoYCrCb(rgb)
            rgb_image[x][y] = ycrcb         
    return rgb_image

def RGBtoYCrCb(rgb):
    """ Converts RGB vector to YCrCb vector

    Keyword arguments:
    rgb -- list of size 3: [r,g,b]

    Returns: YCrCr color (list of size 3: [y,cr,cb])
    """

    r,g,b = float(rgb[0]),float(rgb[1]),float(rgb[2])
    y = 0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b
    cb = 128 - 0.1687*r - 0.3313*g + 0.5*b 
    cr = 128 + 0.5*r - 0.4187*g - 0.0813*b

    return [y,cr,cb]

def new_RGBtoYCrCb(image):
    r, g, b = image[..., 0], image[..., 1], image[..., 2]

    y = 0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b
    cb = 128 - 0.1687*r - 0.3313*g + 0.5*b 
    cr = 128 + 0.5*r - 0.4187*g - 0.0813*b

    return np.dstack((y, cr, cb))

def new_RGBtoYCrCb2(image):
    M = np.array([[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],
                  [0.5, - 0.4187, - 0.0813],
                  [-0.1687, - 0.3313, 0.5]])
    result = M.dot(image.reshape(-1, 3).T).T
    result[..., 1:] += 128.0
    return result.reshape(image.shape)

image = coffee() / 255.0
result = new_RGBtoYCrCb(image)
print(np.allclose(result, imageRGBtoYCrCb(image)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, [`np.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) does not do 'proper' vectorization, in the sense that all the looping over axes is still done in Python. Although it offers nicer syntax, you shouldn't expect it to perform much faster than a standard Python `for` loop.

One way to avoid looping in Python is to use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which lets you perform tensor contractions using Einstein summation notation. Axes with repeated subscript labels are summed over - in this case we want to sum over the second axis of `matr_to_ycrcb_mult` and the third axis of `rgb_image` (the `j` subscript).

For example:

```
def rgb2ycrcb_einsum(rgb_image):
    out = np.einsum('ij,xyj->xyi', matr_to_ycrcb_mult, rgb_image)
    out[..., -2:] += 128
    return out
```

This already buys a big performance improvement over applying `np.dot` to each pixel using `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
rgb_image = np.random.random_integers(0, 255, (1024, 768, 3))

ycrbr_image1 = imageRGBtoYCrCb(rgb_image)
ycrbr_image2 = rgb2ycrcb_einsum(rgb_image)

print(np.allclose(ycrbr_image1, ycrbr_image2))
# True

%timeit imageRGBtoYCrCb(rgb_image)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 3.95 s per loop

%timeit rgb2ycrcb_einsum(rgb_image)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 165 ms per loop
```

### Update

It's possible to do quite a lot better using `numpy.core.umath_tests.inner1d`:

```
def rgb2ycrcb_inner1d(rgb_image):
    out = inner1d(matr_to_ycrcb_mult[None, None, :], rgb_image[..., None, :])
    out[..., -2:] += 128
    return out

%timeit rgb2ycrcb_inner1d(rgb_image)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 34.6 ms per loop
```

### Update 2

YXD's solution using `np.dot` seems to be the fastest so far, beating `inner1d` by a factor of 3 (presumably by leveraging BLAS-accelerated matrix multiplication).

```
def rgb2ycrcb_dot(rgb_image):
    out = matr_to_ycrcb_mult.dot(rgb_image.reshape(-1, 3).T).T
    out[..., -2:] += 128
    return out.reshape(rgb_image.shape)

%timeit rgb2ycrcb_dot(rgb_image)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the timings